# Why does static_cast allow downcasts when logically it should refuse them for safety purposes or static_cast is not about safety?

Tags: c++

In the following example the compiler accepts the `static_cast` downcast resulting in undefined behavior while I thought `static_cast` was all about safety (that C-style casts were unable to provide).

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    int x = 10;
};
class Derived1: public Base 
{
public:
    int y = 20;

};
class Derived2 : public Base 
{
public:
    int z = 30;
    int w = 40;

};

int main() {

    Derived1 d1;

    Base* bp1 = static_cast<Base*>(&d1);
    Derived2* dp1 = static_cast<Derived2*>(bp1);

    std::cout << dp1->z << std::endl; // outputs 20
    std::cout << dp1->w << std::endl; // outputs random value
}
```

Comment: I don't think anybody ever pretended that C++ is a safe language.

Comment: Nope, for downcasting with safety you need `dynamic_cast`(and null checks)  - `static_cast` tells the compiler you are 100% sure you have the right type

Comment: Upcast is performed implicitly, no special syntax required. The point of `static_cast` is largely to be able to explicitly perform the reverse of implicit conversions. It is generally impossible to verify at compile time that such a conversion is valid - if it were, the compiler would allow it implicitly.

Comment: Observe that the CRTP relies on this.

Comment: `static_cast` is "safe" in the sense that it doesn't let you convert between unrelated types. The safety goal of C++ is pretty much to not be quite as unsafe as C.

Comment: `static_cast` provides all of the safety that can be provided at zero cost. `dynamic_cast` provides more safety but it comes with a cost attached.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought `static_cast` was all about safety (that C style cast were unable to provide)

`static_cast` *is* safer than a C-style cast. But not because it's impossible to go wrong with it. It's safer because it's only *less likely* to go wrong. When we write a C-style cast, a compiler will go through [this list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) to appease us:

> When the C-style cast expression is encountered, the compiler attempts
>   to interpret it as the following cast expressions, in this order:
>
> 1. `const_cast<new_type>(expression)`;
> 2. `static_cast<new_type>(expression)`, with extensions: pointer or reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) even if the base class is inaccessible (that is, this cast ignores the private inheritance specifier). Same applies to casting pointer to member to pointer to member of unambiguous non-virtual base;
> 3. `static_cast` (with extensions) followed by `const_cast`;
> 4. `reinterpret_cast<new_type>(expression)`;
> 5. `reinterpret_cast` followed by `const_cast`.
>
> The first choice that satisfies the requirements of the respective
>   cast operator is selected, even if it cannot be compiled (see
>   example). If the cast can be interpreted in more than one way as
>   `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`, it cannot be compiled.   In
>   addition, C-style cast notation is allowed to cast from, to, and
>   between pointers to incomplete class type. If both expression and
>   new_type are pointers to incomplete class types, it's unspecified
>   whether `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` gets selected.

The point in favoring `static_cast` to *that*, is that you have a finer grained control over the resulting cast, which does grant a measure of added safety. But it doesn't change the fact that the C++ object model requires that `static_cast` support casting even when undefined behavior is possible. Only `dynamic_cast` (not on the above list, by the way) has an added bit of safety for polymorphic types, but that's not without overhead.

Answer (score 16):

You use `dynamic_cast` only really when you are not sure if the cast is going to succeed and you catch exceptions or check for nullptr. However if you are *sure* your downcasting is going to succeed, the language allows you to use `static_cast` (which is cheaper). If you were wrong, that is your problem. In an ideal world every cast would succeed in 100% of the time. But we don't live in an ideal world. It's a bit like array subscript. `arr[5]` means "I am absolutely sure this array has at least 6 elements. Compiler doesn't need to check". If your array was smaller than you expected, that's again your problem.

Answer (score 5):

I don't really know what to tell you. Why does it allow such a cast? For when you need/want one.

Don't want to use it? Don't! You could switch to `dynamic_cast` (more expensive), or *don't cast*.

C++ lets you do plenty of things that require thought and care. This is one of them.

But it *is* still safer than C. The `static_cast` won't let you cast `bp1` to an `UrgleBurgle*`, for example.

Of course ultimately you can still use the C-style casts if you like. I mean, I wouldn't advise it, but you could. C++ is all about *choice* (usually between a terrible option and a slightly less terrible option).